# Research question: What are the mentions of seasons along with lunar months or lunar phases in Mahabharata

Tags: mahabharata, vyasa, itihasa, calendar, research

Research question: What are the citations of seasons along with lunar Hindu months or lunar phases in Mahabharata?

This is extremely important tool for dating Mahabharata, using precession of equinoxes and seasons, which is a strong proof.

---

**As of now, there are three well known such citations. Are there more such descriptions present?**

**1. Pandavas in Vana Vasa**

> 16 teṣāṃ puṇyatamā rātriḥ parva saṃdhau sma śāradī       tatraiva
> vasatām āsīt kārtikī janamejaya
>
> And, O Janamejaya, the holiest night, that of the full moon in the
> month of Kartika in the season of autumn, was spent by them while
> dwelling there!

[Vana Parva, CE 179:16](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/mbs/mbs03179.htm)  ([Translation](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m03/m03181.htm))

**2. Krishna's mission of Peace.**

> 7 kaumude māsi revatyāṃ śarad ante himāgame
> sphītasasyamukhe kāle
> kalyaḥ sattvavatāṃ varaḥ
>
> The month was (Kaumuda Kartika) under the constellation Revati. It was
> the season of dew, Autumn having departed.

[Udyoga Pava, CE 81: 7](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/mbs/mbs05081.htm) ([Translation](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m05/m05083.htm))

**3. Bhishma Nirvana**

> 6 sa niryayau gajapurād yājakaiḥ parivāritaḥ       dṛṣṭvā nivṛttam
> ādityaṃ pravṛttaṃ cottarāyaṇam
>
> Accompanied by a number of priests he then set out of the city named
> after the elephant, having seen that the sun ceasing to go southwards
> had begun to proceed in his northward course.
>
> 28 māgho 'yaṃ samanuprāpto māsaḥ puṇyo yudhiṣṭhira
> tribhāgaśeṣaḥ pakṣo 'yaṃ śuklo bhavitum arhati
>
> O Yudhishthira, the lunar month of Magha has come. This is, again, the
> lighted fortnight and a fourth part of it ought by this (according to
> my calculations) be over.

[Anushasana Parva, CE 153: 6,28](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/mbs/mbs13153.htm)  ([Translation](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m13/m13b132.htm))

Comment: List like Q/A are off topic.. there might be tens/hundreds of such mentions...and answer would never be complete..pls make this more focused..for research, you have to process entire MBH text, Q/A won't help much here..

Comment: @YDS there are no thousands, infact there could be at best like 2 to 5 imho. As these are citations from a scripture, this cannot be off topic

Comment: @YDS I will be grateful if you could even point one more such description.

Comment: here u go (for Dhritarashtra's vanprastha) https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m15/m15011.htm ..actually, there r many in MBH..and this is TOO LONG to answer..

Comment: @YDS where is the season mentioned??

Comment: @YDS can you please copy paste the passage here??

Comment: @YDS Ok, I humbly think you have not understood my question at all. Please read and understand a question thoroughly before flagging it.

Comment: Could this be a wiki or community question?

Comment: @sbharti what is that?

Comment: Pls see this https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts. There is a "Community Wiki" checkbox on bottom right when you attempt to answer a question. This way you're just building up the info as and when it arrives. Your question is fit for such a post iMO.

Comment: @sbharti thanks

Comment: @YDS do you have any answers? If you have please write it, so bounty doesn't go waste

Comment: @Vivikta yes, but in Mahabharata it's rarely used.